# Is there a utility like Tweak UI that I can use for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-interface

I realize Microsoft stopped supporting Tweak UI with WinXP. I always liked its features to get rid of small annoyances. Is there a single go-to place for an app like that now with Win7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ultimate Windows Tweaker isn't bad:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-v2-a-tweak-ui-for-windows-7-vista

Comment: Great tool....!

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of tweak utilities(freeware / free tools) available for windows 7.

[EnhanceMySe7en](http://www.seriousbit.com/tweak_windows_7/)

[Little Tweaker](http://leelusoft.blogspot.com/2009/05/windows-7-little-tweaker.html)

[Ultimate Windows Tweaker](http://www.winvistaclub.com/Ultimate_Windows_Tweaker.html) as mentioned by xpda

[XDN Tweaker](http://xenomorph.net/?page_id=336)

[TweakNow PowerPack](http://www.tweaknow.com/powerPack.html) as mentioned by xiaolai &

[Win Secret](http://www.tweaknow.com/WinSecret.html)

[Giga Tweaker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/GIGATweaker.shtml)

[Argente Utilities](http://www.softpedia.com/progScreenshots/Argente-Utilities-Screenshot-140452.html)

[Tweak Star](http://tweakstar.com/index.php)

[AutoMz Ultimate Tweaker](http://www.mztweak.com/AutoMz.html)

Comment: Nice tools. You might want to re-check the second link!

Answer (score 2):

check out here: http://www.tweaknow.com/
it works for windows vista, and I've used it on windows 7, looks great.

Comment: Is that link OK? I can't reach it.

Comment: It works for me

Comment: It works for me now. Must have been a temporary problem. Or aliens.